# Is ubuntu Mate good choise for Laptop?

Tags: 14.04

---

With few capabilities:
celeron Processor
4gb ram
ssd

what would be fastest distro for this Laptop?

and Command line and suppoerted programms(skzpe,virtualbox and so on) is seem in ubuntu and ubuntu mate?

Answer (score 0):

See this article, where Ubuntu MATE is recommended as the best distro for laptops ☺️

- https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/878620-the-best-linux-distros-of-2016

Comment: I've been interested in Mate but what keeps me from using it on my laptop is the lack of tap to click. That's basically a deal breaker, especially since it is such a common thing to have.